# Rearranging an address in a SAS data set

Tags: string, sas

So I have a SAS dataset that contains information such as a persons name and address. I am trying to arrange the addresses so all the apartment information is at the end. For example:

`Name              Address
Jon Doe          105 Park Ave APT 500
John Smith       APT 250 1690 Heading ST
Amy Squiq        102 Intel Drive APT 89 Portville`

I would like to have all the addresses in the format as the first observation (Where the apartment number is at the end)

This is what I originally had:

```
DATA list;
INPUT name $1-10 address $11-50 ;
DATALINES;
Joe Smith 105 Park Ave APT 500
John Smith APT 250 1690 Heading ST
Amy Squig 102 Intel Drive APT 89 Portville
Joe Dirtt 1305 dork CT APT 845
;
RUN;    

data want;
  set list;
  ad=findw(address, "APT");
  ad2=substr(address, ad,ad+6);
  ad3=substr(ad2,1,7);
run;
```

The problem I had with this was removing the "APT ..." in the original address. With the help from Stu Sztukowski I was able to add in a piece and the final product works.

```
data want;
  set list;
  ad=findw(address, "APT");
  ad2=substr(address, ad,ad+6);
  ad3=substr(ad2,1,7);
  _apt_removed = compbl(tranwrd(upcase(address),trim(ad3), '') );
  new_address = catx(' ', propcase(_apt_removed), ad3);
run;
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question as it's currently posed, and can't be answered here.  It's also not really answerable anywhere without all of your data, because there are all sorts of complications to this (identifying what the apartment number is, is not easy).

Comment: Apartment number is always the following 4 characters following APT. It is not possible to give you all of my data so I gave you an example of the three combinations I have seen.

Comment: First, that's not in the question - add it.  Second, you still haven't presented a programming problem.  What is the programming problem you don't understand how to solve?  What methods do you know for finding, separating, and combining strings - and what about those methods doesn't work for this?

Comment: Based on SO rules, you do need to post an attempt, try using SCAN() and Substr() to parse out the parts of an address and see how that works. If you need further help, please post what you've tried up to that point and you'll receive further help. You can also post at communities.sas.com which does not have these rules, but you'll likely get similar responses regarding attempts and clarification.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to post an "attempt", but it has to be sufficiently specific to be a programming question and not just a "how do I do my job" question, and it has to have enough detail in it as to what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, I recommend that you post only programming questions. If you rephrase your original question to be programmatic, you will be more likely to get help from others. The way your question is currently worded is more suitable for [communities.sas.com](http://communities.sas.com);  however, I will give you help since I was somewhat interested in this solving the problem upon reading it.

The below code will search the string backwards and return the position of the word "APT." If it's > 2, then it must not be at the end of the string. If it's <= 2, it's at the end of the string and we just want to copy the address.

A number always follows the word "APT," so we store this in a temporary variable. We then create our apartment number part of the address by concatenating `APT` and `_apt_num`.

Next, we search the original address and remove `APT <number>` from it. This whole new string is enclosed by the `compbl` function to change any extra double-spaces to single spaces as a result of the removal process.

Finally, we take our new string and attach `APT <number>` to the end of it.

```
data want;
    set have;

    _apt_pos = findw(upcase(address), 'APT',' ','BE');
    if(_apt_pos > 2) then do;
        _apt_num = scan(upcase(address), _apt_pos-1, ' ',  'B');
        _apt_string = cat('APT', ' ', _apt_num);
        _apt_removed = compbl(tranwrd(upcase(address),trim(_apt_string), '') );
        new_address = catx(' ', propcase(_apt_removed), 'APT', _apt_num);
    end;
        else new_address = address;

    drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. This worked and I will remember to post an example of what I have tried in the future.